# How do I insert images into a Google Sheet in Python using gspread (or any other package)?

Tags: image, google-sheets, gspread

I need a way to insert an image into a specific cell in a specific Google Sheet. If there is any python package and/or slice of code that can accomplish this, please let me know. As far as I am aware Gspread does not have anything helpful.

Comment: Can you please provide more details of your code and what is not working for you? To provide more details you can review this guide - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry if I confused you, I don't have a problem with the code. I want to write a new section of the code, that would add an image to a cell. However, I have no idea how to do that, that is why I asked. I have a Google Sheets API set up and working, all I need now if a way to insert the image.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply insert an image from an URL with a formula like this:

```
'=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={}")'.format(file_id)
```

When you insert/upload the data be sure to choose **USER_ENTERED** for value input option. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption

With gspred:

```
sheet_instance.insert_rows(rows, value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')
```

Answer (score 1):

Overall to add image into Google Sheets can be accomplished with Python by first inserting the image file in Google Drive using the Google Drive API:

Here is how to insert it to google drive. - https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#examples,

and secondly linking to the image in Google Sheets with the Google Sheets API, Here is Google sheets API - https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#CellData

Note: Look under CellData

Answer (score 0):

To do so follow these steps :

- First load the image to the drive and share it
- Get the file id of your image in the drive
- Then this is the code using `gspread` python package:

```py
image_id = "" # put the id
insert_image = '=IMAGE(f"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={image_id}")'
sheet_range = "" # Add where you want to insert the image for example A2:A2 to insert the image into the cell A2
sheet.update(sheet_range, [[insert_image]], value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

And that's it
(of course you can use any method of gspread based on your need update / update_batch / insert_row etc) but don't forget `value_input_option="USER_ENTERED"`

Hope this helps